# Google sheets parse json

Tags: google-sheets

I have in my google sheets cell(A10) json object with price: `{"bitcoin":{"usd":45258}}`

How do I parse this price number and exctract it to do something?

Like for example in C10 cell I want to write: `"=A10['bitcoin']['usd']*B10"`

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Answer (score 4):

This function may help.

```js
function getData(json, path) {
  const obj = JSON.parse(json);
  const keys = path.split('.');
  let current = obj;
  for( key of keys ){
    current = current[key];
  }
  return current;
}
```

And you can write in C10 like this:

```
=getData(A10, "bitcoin.usd")*B10
```

Chain the property names with "."

Here is a [sample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iD9CRzqys5oY7YG_knucC236T9M5hJgPdSdGq7fAIpk/edit?usp=sharing). Feel free to make a copy and check it.

[image]

Comment: Hi! thanks for the answer! where do I input this function getData(json, path)?

Comment: In the Script Editor as a Google Apps Script. You can open the Script Editor by clicking [Tools] - [Script Editor] on your spreadsheet. I'll add a picture of my sample.