# Google Sheets - Parse JSON string contained in one cell and extract specific values to another cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet where for each row in column Z there is a JSON string recovered from Twitter via [TAGS](https://tags.hawksey.info/).

[image]

The JSON strings in column Z all have a similar structure:

```
{
  "hashtags": [
    {
      "text": "Negev_Summit",
      "indices": [
        172,
        185
      ]
    }
  ],
  "symbols": [],
  "user_mentions": [
    {
      "screen_name": "JY_LeDrian",
      "name": "Jean-Yves Le Drian",
      "id": 1055021191,
      "id_str": "1055021191",
      "indices": [
        69,
        80
      ]
    }
  ],
  "urls": [],
  "media": [
    {
      "id": 1513588335893258200,
      "id_str": "1513588335893258240",
      "indices": [
        271,
        294
      ],
      "media_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/media/FQFYknkXoAAxgYd.jpg",
      "media_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/media/FQFYknkXoAAxgYd.jpg",
      "url": "https://twitter.com/yairlapid/status/1513588345468825605",
      "display_url": "pic.twitter.com/dA4cBepIh2",
      "expanded_url": "https://twitter.com/yairlapid/status/1513588345468825605/photo/1",
      "type": "photo",
      "sizes": {
        "medium": {
          "w": 1024,
          "h": 576,
          "resize": "fit"
        },
        "thumb": {
          "w": 150,
          "h": 150,
          "resize": "crop"
        },
        "large": {
          "w": 1024,
          "h": 576,
          "resize": "fit"
        },
        "small": {
          "w": 680,
          "h": 383,
          "resize": "fit"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to extract specific values for each JSON string in column Z and put them in columns AA, AB and AC (hashtags, user mentions, and URL's).

I've managed to achieve this with a really dirty multiple REGEXREPLACE formula but it doesn't seem logical that there is no way to fo this more efficiently:

```
=IFERROR("@"&JOIN(" @",SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXEXTRACT(INDIRECT("Y"&ROW()),".*user_mentions\"":\[(.*)\],\""urls.*"),"(,\""indices\"":\[\d+,\d+\])",""),"(,\""id_str\"":\""\d+\"")",""),"(,\""id\"":\d+)",""),"(\{\""screen_name\"":\"")",""),"\"",\""name\"":\""(.){1,50}\""\}",""),",")),"")
```

Ideally i'm looking for a script which would parse the JSON string and extract 1 or more values from each section of the JSON. For example:

For hashtags (column AA):

```
=PARSEJSON(Z1, "hashtags")
```

Result:

```
#hashtag1 #hashtag2
```

For user_mentions (column AB):

```
=PARSEJSON(Z1, "user_mentions/screen_name")
```

Result:

```
@username1 @username2
```

Would appreciate any help sending me in the right direction.

Comment: how do you organize your data in the spreadsheet? what happens if you only filter the values in `screen_name` in a separate cell? how are you using the fetch method to get the data?

Comment: I'm using TAGS (https://tags.hawksey.info) to get the data. The JSON strings from the example above are stored in column Y. Ideally, i'd like to display the "screen_names" in column AA.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it with a different script I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69174389/18719143).

This is the script:

```js
function getData(json, path) {
  const obj = JSON.parse(json);
  const keys = path.split('.');
  let current = obj;
  for( key of keys ){
    current = current[key];
  }
  return current;
}
```

You would then enter in the cell with `=getData(Z1, "hashtags")`

Comment: Tried the code in your answer. I get an empty cell :-( I have updated the JSON in my question to the one I tested your code on. Normally I should have got `Negev_Summit` as a hashtag result but got nothing ?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get any of the solutions to work.
Ultimately this is the script that worked for me.

```
function getData(jsonText, key) {
  try {
    var data = JSON.parse(jsonText);
    return data[key] || "";
  } catch (error) {
    return "Error parsing JSON or key not found.";
  }
}
```

Calling out the element you need in the cell using: `=getData(A2, "title")`

- Replace A2 with the cell containing your JSON data
- Replace title with the element to parse from your data

Comment: I like this solution as well.  I found that my json values were single quoted, i.e:  `{'cpu_user':1.234}`.  The single-quotes caused the JSON.parse() call to fail.  The JSON.parse() call seems to prefer keys that are double-quoted, like: `{"cpu_user":1.234}`.

Answer (score 0):

If your main purpose is to only get the values in `screen_name` I'd modify my [script](https://www.chicagocomputerclasses.com/google-sheets-import-json-importjson-function/) and I'd use `=IMPORTJSON(url, "user_mentions/screen_name")`

```
/**
* Imports JSON data to your spreadsheet Ex: IMPORTJSON("http://myapisite.com","city/population")
* @param url URL of your JSON data as string
* @param xpath simplified xpath as string
* @customfunction
*/
function IMPORTJSON(url,xpath){
  
  try{
    var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    var content = res.getContentText();
    var json = JSON.parse(content);
    
    var patharray = xpath.split("/");
    
    for(var i=0;i<patharray.length;i++){
      json = json[patharray[i]];
    }
    
    
    if(typeof(json) === "undefined"){
      return "Node Not Available";
    } else if(typeof(json) === "object"){
      var tempArr = [];
      
      for(var obj in json){
        tempArr.push([obj,json[obj]]);
      }
      return tempArr;
    } else if(typeof(json) !== "object") {
      return json;
    }
  }
  catch(err){
      return "Error getting data";  
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Hey David, indeed when I researched my problem I came across your script, however, it expects a URL for the JSON while in my project, the JSON segments are already fetched and stored in cells, hundreds of them all along column Y.

Comment: I tried modulating your script instead of looking for the JSON in a URL, to get it from the active cell, however i keep on getting "Error getting data".

Comment: @EladRatson do you have a sample sheet I can take a look at?

Comment: Somehow your comment slipped me. Apologize. Here is a link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10jBQaiTVFHj9sg987OZmjfeFK0Ffit4X5PouIIHT1qk/edit?usp=sharing . Note that the raw JSON is in column AA

Answer (score 0):

@Yiddy s answer did not work for me. So i did some modifications to it and came up with this.

```
function getData(range, path, sheet_name) {
    var sprsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = sprsheet.getSheetByName(sheet_name);

    var string = sheet.getRange(range).getValue();

    var json = JSON.parse(string);
    const keys = path.split('.');

    var current = json;
    for (key of keys) {
        current = current[key];
    }
    return current;
}
```